# How to run Spring Boot with external configuration in Windows CMD?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and I'm runnig it java -jar command on CMD. But I need to use external config file that is application.properties in C:\ folder. To do this I'm running the application with this command:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.name=application --spring.config.location=file:///C:/
```

But command doesn't cares the spring.config.location property and application.properties file can't be found. Because of this the application not working.

How can I run the app with spring.config.name and spring.config.location parameters in Windows CMD?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you should use `file://sample-app/application.yml`

On Windows you should use `file:///C:/sample-app/application.yml`

Answer (score -1):

You try placing the jar and application.properties files in same folder and run java -jar yourapplication.jar

See if it works.